# Discord Visual Studio playing game

Tags: visual-studio, discord

I've recently been making a bot and it seems that I dont know how to change the playing game to "w!help for a list of cmds" please help!

Answer (score 0):

in discord.net .9.6 put

```
client.Ready += Client_Ready;
```

then sometime after that put

```
private void Client_Ready(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.SetGame("YOUR GAME");
    }
```

hope this helps